# Syntax error near `|` DELETE using the NebulaGraph database

Tags: nebula-graph

I was using the Nebula Graph database, and when I executed the following statement

`match (o:HO_NEO4J_OBJECT_ID) - [r] - (a:HO_NEO4J_PERM) where r.hoid in [“1604715734952239104”] return id(o) as src, id(a) as dst | DELETE EDGE REFERENCES_OBJECTID_PERM $-.src → $-.dst`

Error appeared like:
https://discuss.nebula-graph.com.cn/uploads/default/original/2X/f/f1808aa86ce80984a8137f96d1dfe09082c89eae.png

Answer (score 0):

MATCH statement and DELETE cannot be mixed.

The alternative is
`lookup on HO_NEO4J_OBJECT_ID where HO_NEO4J_OBJECT_ID.hoid=="1604715734952239104" yield id(vertex) as src | go from $-.src over * where "HO_NEO4J_PERM" in labels($$) yield $-.src as src, id($$) as dst | delete edge REFERENCES_OBJECTID_PERM $-.src -> $-.dst`